# passbook pass not added

Tags: iphone, passbook

I am having trouble to add my self created passbook pass.pkpass package to the passbook app.
 I can open the package and it shows on the iPhone device, but when i press add to add this pass to the passbook app it is not working.
The log tells me:
Invalid data reading pass xxx. Signature must contain a signing date.
Whats wrong here during pass creation / signing ? 
There is definitely something wrong with my new pass type id certificate uploaded because with the old one it was working ?

Comment: How did you manage to see the log? Im using console.app and when I add the passbook to the simulator nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not signing the pass correctly.

iOS 7 introduced the need to include a date in the signed time attribute.

See this question for more information

[Signing content for apple passbook in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874074/signing-content-for-apple-passbook-in-c-sharp/19002518#19002518)