# Signing Apple's passbook passes

Tags: c#, signing, passbook

I am trying to sign a manifest.json file in C# for Apple Passbook passes. I've followed [Apple's guide for signing passes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW55) and looked at posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874074/signing-content-for-apple-passbook-in-c-sharp) and [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/MobileLOB/archive/2012/07/30/part-3ndashpassbook-server.aspx). When I execute the code, a CryptographicException occurs at the line `signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);` saying that

> Key does not exist

This is the code I currently have:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String manifest = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Testpass\Testpass\manifest.json");
        byte[] msgBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(manifest);
        byte[] sign = SignMsg(msgBytes, findCertificate(true));

        //byte[] sign = signit(manifest);
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Testpass\Testpass", sign);


    }

    private byte[] SignMsg(Byte[] msg, X509Certificate2 signerCert)
    {
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(msg);
        SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);

        X509Certificate2 developerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\pass.cer");
        X509Certificate2 appleWWDRCA = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\AppleWWDRCA.cer");
        CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, developerCertificate);
        cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
        cmsSigner.Certificates.Add(appleWWDRCA);
        cmsSigner.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.Now));

        //  Sign the CMS/PKCS #7 message.
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);

        //  Encode the CMS/PKCS #7 message.
        return signedCms.Encode();
    }
```

Is it neccessary to get the certificates from the Windows Certificate Store, or is getting it from the file system OK? Any help on how to fix the problem is appreciated!

PS: I have also looked at [DotNet-Passbook](https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook), but first of all it [created some problems](https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook/issues/25) for me, and second, I really only need the signing of the manifest file, not everything else that the library provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the creator of dotnet-passbook.

This error looks like your certificate doesn't include the private key component.

When you open the certificate in Windows, it will indicate whether or not the private key is included.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the certificate, it does not say "You have a private key ..." like some of my other certificates say. How do I fix this?

Comment: When you export the certificate from Windows, you need to ensure that you choose to include the private key. If you're doing it from OS X, you must expand the certificate and select both the cert and key when performing the export.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness Have you thought of converting the dotnet-passbook to use .net core? Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't considered it to date, since nobody has requested it. I will take a look. I guess the solution is to make the Nuget package compatible with .Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: @LyubomirVelchev I've created a new branch of dotnet-passbook, which contains my first pass at .Net Standard support. I thought you might be interested.